# Navigation - transparent, horizontale center, difficult with Subnavigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, mouseover, transparent

i would create this [Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KztNJ.jpg).
i have try some things with css and js.
but it works not on every browser and i think the code is dirty.

the driangle of the navigation-hover is center of the length. the transparent driangle is lay under the blue driangle and the body of the Subnavigation (or undernavigation) is flexible in width.

have you some ideas to create this navigation clean? and possibly without JS?

i hope you can help me. i have spend so much hours and it does nt correct work.

yours, yellow

```js
$( ".active" ).mouseover(function() {

  var xbreite = this.offsetWidth;
  //Breite von nav-sub
  var ybreite = this.nextElementSibling.offsetWidth;

  var zbreite = ybreite - xbreite; 
  var xb = xbreite/2;
  xb = xb - 23;
  var zb = ybreite - xb;
  xb = xb+"px";
  zb = zb+"px";
  
  // console.log(this.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild);
   //div rest -> aber bekomme kein element und style unter gebracht
 
  var rest = this.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
  rest.style.width=xb;
  
  var eck = this.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.lastElementChild;
  eck.style.width=zb;
  
  //Subnav sichtbar machen
//  this.nextElementSibling.style.top='59px';
    this.nextElementSibling.style.visibility='visible';
});


//Subnavi schließen
$( ".nav-sub" ).mouseleave(function() {
  
  var navsubs = $('.nav-sub');
  var subsCount = $(navsubs).length;
  
  for( hilf = 0; hilf < subsCount; hilf++){
    //navsubs[hilf].style.top='-9999999px';
  navsubs[hilf].style.visibility='hidden';}
});
```

```css
.bcg{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}

.header{
 position:fixed;
 height:84px;
  z-index:10;
 background-color:#579dd3;
 opacity: 0.75;
  width:100%;
 z-index: 100;
}

.logo{ 
 float:left;
 padding-left:1.875em;
 padding-top:0.938em;
}

.nav{
 float:left;
}

/* Navigation Primär */
.nav-prim{
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  position:absolute;
  right:1.64em;
  bottom: -1.2em;
  font-size:17px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  z-index:999;
}

/* Dreieck Navigation Primär */
.nav-prim ul li a {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-prim ul li a:hover::after{
background-image: url("http://mattgelb.canopus.uberspace.de/nav_active.png");
    bottom: -12px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 65px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }

/*Aktiver Link */
.nav-prim .active{
    position: relative;
}

.nav-prim .active::after{
background-image: url("http://mattgelb.canopus.uberspace.de/nav_active.png");
    bottom: -12px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 65px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

/* Ende Dreieck Navigation Primär */



.nav-prim ul li{
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0.7em;
  padding-right:0.7em;
/*  position: relative; */
}

.nav-prim ul li:last-child{
  padding-right:0;
}

.nav-prim ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
height:56px;
display:block;
}










/* Subnavigation */
.nav-sub{
  position:absolute;
  color:blue;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  z-index:11111;
 visibility:hidden;
 top: 59px;
 /* 
display:none;*/

}

.nav-sub li{
  clear:both;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0;
  background-color:white;
  width:100%; 

}

.nav-sub li:first-child{
  background-color:transparent;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  
  
} 

.nav-sub .eck{
  background-image:url('http://mattgelb.canopus.uberspace.de/nav_bg_active.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:25px;
  float:left;
}

.nav-sub .rest{
  background-color:white;
  height:25px;
  width:30%;float:left;
}

.nav-sub a{
  color:blue !important;
  text-transform:none;
  
  
}

.nav-sub a:hover{
  color:red !important;
  background-image:none !important;
}

.nav-sub a:hover::after{
   border:0 !important; 
  background-image:none !important;
}
```

```html
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 

<img class="bcg" src="http://www.jessicajonesdesign.com/downloads/lines-wallpaper-orange.gif"> 
  
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
           <a href="index.html"><img width="60" src="https://davidwalsh.name/demo/codepenLogo.png"></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="nav"> 
      <div class="nav-prim">  
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="active" href="#">Tätigkeitsbereiche</a>
                <ul class="nav-sub"> 
                  <li>  
                    <div class="rest"></div> 
                    <div class="eck"></div>    
                  </li>  
                  <li><a href="#g">Seite 1</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="#g">Coperate dsfsdfsdf Events  blubb blieeee</a></li>
                </ul> 
                
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Leistungen</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Projekte</a>
                
              </li> 
              <li>  
                <a class="active" href="#">Fähigkeiten</a> 
                <ul class="nav-sub"> 
                  <li>  
                    <div class="rest"></div>   
                    <div class="eck"></div>    
                  </li>  
                  <li><a href="#g">Seite 1</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="#g">Coperate dsfsdfsdf Events  blubb blieeee</a></li>
                </ul> 
                
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Aktuelles</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use something like this

The HTML

```
<div class="nav"> 
      <div class="nav-prim">  
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="active" href="#">Tätigkeitsbereiche</a>
                <ul class="nav-sub"> 
                  <li>  
                    <div class="rest">
                      <div class="eck"></div> 
                    </div> 

                  </li>  
                  <li><a href="#g">Seite 1</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="#g">Coperate dsfsdfsdf Events  blubb blieeee</a></li>
                </ul> 

              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Leistungen</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Projekte</a>

              </li> 
              <li>  
                <a class="active" href="#">Fähigkeiten</a> 
                <ul class="nav-sub"> 
                  <li>  
                    <div class="rest"><div class="eck"></div></div>   

                  </li>  
                  <li><a href="#g">Seite 1</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="#g">Coperate dsfsdfsdf Events  blubb blieeee</a></li>
                </ul> 

              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Aktuelles</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And some css

```
body
{
  background-color : #eeeeee;
}
div.nav ul
{
    list-style-type : none;
}

div.nav ul li
{
    font-family: Arial, Haettenschweiler, "Arial Narrow Bold", sans-serif;
    color:black;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  position : relative;
  background-color : #0000ff;
}

div.nav a
{
    color:black;    
}

div.nav li ul 
{
    display: none;
    position : absolute;
    top : 100%;
    left : -40px;
    padding-top : 5px;
}

div.nav li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;    
}

div.nav li:hover li 
{
    float:none; 
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;
}

div.nav li:hover li a 
{ 
    min-width: 150px;
    display:block;
}

.rest {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #eeeeee;
  margin-left : 10px;
  position : relative;
}

.eck {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #0000ff;
  margin-left : 10px;
  position : absolute;
  top : -25px;
  left : -30px;
  z-index : 999;
}
```

You can also view the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/x8x2L93u/

Comment: Oh i see it works not 100% correct.

if the name of the subnavigation is longer then the primare navigation, the link broke. but the box of the subnavigation should width:100%. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: And i see that the driangle in the subnavigation is not transparent :(